# Laravel | Fetch Count of Items in Categories

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have following 2 Tables:

Ad: {id, title, category_id} Category: {id, name, parent_id}

Table 1: Ad

```
---|----------------------------|------------
id | title                      | category_id
---|----------------------------|------------
1  | Ad in Cars category        | 2
2  | Another Ad in Cars category| 2
3  | Ad in Vehicles category    | 1
```

Table 2: Category

```
---|-----------|-----------
id | name      | parent_id
---|-----------|-----------
1  | Vehicles  | NULL
2  | Cars      | 1
```

Now I need to fetch Categories and count of ads in each category. Also, if a category has ads in child categories, then the count of ads for a parent category should also include ads belonging to child category.

So if I fetch the count of ads in Vehicle category, I should get:

```
Category | Count
---------|-----------
Vehicles | 3
```

And if I fetch count of ads in Cars Category, I should get:

```
Category | Count
---------|-----------
Cars     | 2
```

How do I achieve this in Laravel? I'm using Laravel 5.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but rather a head start. Assuming you have relationship set already in the Category model as `hasMany(Ad)`, you can do

```
$categories = Category::withCount('ads')->get();
```

This will give you all the categories with their count of 'ads'. You can display like this

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->ads_count; //Pay attention to _count here appended to 'adds'
}
```

Then I guess you can do a foreach loop of all categories, see if they are related and increment their item counts. e.g:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
    if ( $category->subCategories ) {
        foreach( $category->subCategories as $sub) {
            $category->ads_count += $sub->ads_count;
        }
    }
}
```

Just a guide. 
Hope it helps.